# Does this code not work because it will take a long time or is it broken?

Tags: vb.net

I am currently trying to generate random numbers until a user defined amount of identical numbers in a row appears. The numbers range from 1 to 10.

When I want 8 identical numbers in a row it takes between 3 and 5 seconds. It goes through about 5 million random numbers. When I want 9 in a row I have left it for over 45 minutes without any luck.

I thought it would only take about 10 times the amount of time as it did for 8 since 1/10 to the power of 9 is only ten times bigger than to the power of 8.

Is it a problem with my code or have I messed up the maths?

MY CODE:

```
 Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("how many identical numbers in a row do you want")
    Dim many As Integer = Console.ReadLine
    Dim storage(many - 1) As Integer

    Dim complete As Boolean = False
    Dim part As Integer = 0

    Dim count As Integer = 0

    Randomize()
    While complete = False
        count += 1

        storage(part) = Int(Rnd() * 10) + 1
        ' Console.WriteLine(storage(part))
        part += 1
        If part = many Then
            part = 0
        End If

        If storage.Min = storage.Max Then
            complete = True
        End If
    End While

    Console.WriteLine("===========")
    Console.WriteLine(count.ToString("N"))
    Console.WriteLine("===========")
    For i = 0 To many - 1
        Console.WriteLine(storage(i))
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

Comment: If it is an identical number generator why use any form of Rnd at all?  Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the code and read [ask] and take the [tour] to learn how the site works.

Comment: thanks for your response. i read "how to ask" and "tour" and am confused at the number of down-votes i'm getting. is it because i posted all of the code?

Comment: I cant speak for those who down voted, but the post is rather vague and the title is very bad (less a programming question than a request for a code review (OT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one possibility: it could be that the VB Rnd function is written so that it can never work, or it could be that it really does simply take a long time sometimes. You would have to do many trials and average them out to find out if your expected ratio of 1:10 works as expected.

Incidentally, you don't need to keep the last ten numbers. You can just keep a count of how many times the next random number equals the previous number. Also I suggest trying a different RNG (random number generator), for example the .NET one:

```
Module Module1

    Dim rand As New Random()

    Sub Main()
        Console.Write("How many identical numbers in a row do you want: ")
        Dim howMany As Integer = CInt(Console.ReadLine)
        Dim count As Long = 0
        Dim previous = -1
        Dim soFar = 0
        Dim n = 0

        While soFar < howMany
            count += 1

            n = rand.Next(1, 11)
            'Console.Write(n.ToString() & " ")
            If n = previous Then
                soFar += 1
            Else
                'If previous >= 0 Then
                '   Console.WriteLine(" X")
                '   Console.Write(n.ToString() & " ")
                'End If
                previous = n
                soFar = 1
            End If

        End While

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Tries taken: " & count.ToString())

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```